# QTimer doesn't emit timeout signal

Tags: c++, qt

I'm rather new in QT. I'm trying to figure out how QTimer works. I want to print something each time it ticks. But I can't get it working.

testobj.cpp:

```
#include "testobj.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

TestObj::TestObj()
{
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(onTick()));

    timer->start(100);

    cout << "Timer started" << endl;
}

void TestObj::onTick()
{
    cout << "test" << endl;
}
```

testobj.h:

```
#ifndef TESTOBJ
#define TESTOBJ

#include <QObject>

class TestObj: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TestObj();

public slots:
    void onTick();
};

#endif // TESTOBJ
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "testobj.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    TestObj obj;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It returns 1 (true) when i check with isActive. But it doesn't print anything at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TestObj is being instantiated on the stack, not the heap, so it will go out of scope when the constructor is finished, which is before code execution gets round to processing events on the event queue.

Add a member variable to the MainWindow header: -

```
 TestObj* m_testObj;
```

Create the object in the MainWindow constructor: -

```
m_testObj = new TestObj;
```

Remember to delete the object in the destructor

```
delete m_testObj;
```

Comment: Also, (if I remember right) it needs to be on the object tree, or it won't fire.  So `TestObj` needs to be parented to `MainWindow` somehow (either by a constructor parameter, or by calling `setParent`), or the `timerEvent` won't get triggered.

Comment: @phyatt, I don't believe that's correct. So long as the object derives from QObject and includes the Q_OBJECT macro, it should be fine.

Comment: A parent isn’t necessary for a QTimer. It would avoid the need for the delete in the dtor though.